# Add Google Analytics with Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-analytics

Does anyone know how to add Google Analytics in my iOS application using SWIFT.
But without using cocoa-pods.

Thanks

Comment: [Do you know that you can use Objective-C libraries with Swift?](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Comment: yes I know that, but what is the default configuration. Should I call this latter with swift code? Is there any tutorial that can i use.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand : " Should I call this latter with swift code?"

Comment: Ok I will add obj-c classes and add in header file. But what to put in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to call the tracker

Comment: Read the guidelines and you will understand. What you do in objective-C yu do in swift